# Getting the value of  previous sibling of an element using JQuery  ^^

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i click to the img i want to get the value of an previous td ..
i try this code but it doesn't work, the alert can't show me the (userid) value

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {    
        var $Edit = $("tbody tr.odd td.hvr img");
        $Edit.click(function() {
        var userid = $(this).prev('td').val();
        alert(userid);
        }
        )
   })
```

the html code :

```
<tbody> 
<tr class="odd"> 
    <td>some</td> 
    <td class="hvr"><img src="EditBtn.png"/></td> 

</tr> 

</tbody>
```

Comment: Read the FAQ please and after that, correct your title and your question.

Comment: Please provide a meaningful question that describes the problem you're having.

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations, while I agree the question was badly composed, and not helped at all by its initial title, I don't believe that the OP failed to make his problem clear.

Comment: @DavidThomas By "question" I meant the initial 'title/heading' that ends with a question mark, not the whole content of the question. I use so much the `title` attribute that it's the first meaning I can think of when I translate from my native language, sorry about that

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations, no problem at all! My apologies, for my presumption. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your attempt, the first is that the `td` is *not* the previous sibling of the `img` element, it's the previous sibling of the `img` element's parent (`td`) element.

The second problem is that a `td` doesn't have a `value` attribute, therefore `val()` is the wrong approach, instead it has `text()`, so try using:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {    
        var $Edit = $("tbody tr.odd td.hvr img");
        $Edit.click(function() {
        var userid = $(this).parent().prev('td').text();
        alert(userid);
        }
        )
   })
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YGbj4/).

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Certainly not with jQuery (you'd think) since it's always: `http://api.jquery.com/ + jquery-method-name + /` ...on the other hand, it's not necessarily easy to realise that when you're first starting. =/

Comment: @user1233875: you're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! ...obviously, if your problem is solved please consider [accepting the solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that most helped you.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your code `this` is the `<img>` tag, not the `td`. Use `closest('td')` to get `<td>` closest to the image.
2. `<td>` tags do not have value, so `val()` won't work. Use `text()` to get the text inside:

Try:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {    
     var $Edit = $("tbody tr.odd td.hvr img");
     $Edit.click(function() {
         var userid = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
         alert(userid);
         })
 })
```